# javascript passing functions nan and undefined errors

Tags: javascript, function

This works tell I hit the tax function. Then I start getting 
nan and undefined errors. Cant figure out why the tax function is not picking up the code from the other functions.

/ Saturday May 27 2017

{
    // Global variables

```
var orderCount = 0;



var takeOrder = function (topping, crustType) {

    // add one to order count

    orderCount = orderCount + 1

    return('Order: ' + crustType + ' pizza topped with ' + topping );

}

var getSubTotal = function(itemCount){

var subTatal = (itemCount * 7.5);
    return (subTatal + ' subtotal of ' + ' itemCount ' + (itemCount));

}

var getTax = function (){

var subTatal = subTatal * 0.06; 

// getTheTax = (subTatal * 0.06) 

return  subTatal + ' with tax of ' + (subTatal)




}


var getTotal = function (){

      var myTotal = getSubTotal + getTax;

  return  ' tax ' + getTax + 'plus subtotal ' + getSubTotal() + ' is ' + (myTotal);

}



console.log(takeOrder('bacon', 'thin crust'));

console.log(takeOrder('cheese', 'thick crust'));

console.log(takeOrder('pepperoni', 'medium crust'));

console.log(getSubTotal(10));

console.log(' getTax ' + getTax());


console.log(getTotal());
```

}

Comment: Maybe it's because `getTax` returns a [string](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/90203/why-is-so-bad-for-concatenation).

Comment: You’re not calling `getSubTotal` and `getTax`, either. (That would use parentheses, as in `getTax()`.)

Comment: There's a difference between `getSubTotal` (the function) and the result of that function when evaluated `getSubTotal()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the corrected version of your code.

```js
var takeOrder = function(topping, crustType) {
    console.log('Order: ' + crustType + ' pizza topped with ' + topping);
    return 1;
}

var getSubTotal = function(orderCount) {
    var subTotal = (orderCount * 7.5);
    console.log('Subtotal of ' + subTotal.toFixed(2) + ' with item count ' + orderCount);
    return subTotal;
}

var getTax = function(subTotal) {
    var tax = subTotal * 0.06;
    console.log('Tax is ' + tax.toFixed(2));
    return tax;
}

var getTotal = function(subTotal, tax) {
    var total = subTotal + tax;
    console.log('Total is ' + total.toFixed(2));
    return total;
}

var orderCount = 0;
orderCount += takeOrder(orderCount, 'bacon', 'thin crust');
orderCount += takeOrder('cheese', 'thick crust');
orderCount += takeOrder('pepperoni', 'medium crust');

var subTotal = getSubTotal(orderCount);
var tax = getTax(subTotal);
var total = getTotal(subTotal, tax);
```

## Summary of corrections

1. Made functions return `Number` rather than `String`
2. Now all functions are almost pure functions (don't cause side-effects other than logging)
3. Formatted numbers prior to printing them by rounding them to the second decimal
4. Fixed typographic errors (`tatal` rather than `total`).
5. Added parenthesis to function invocations (e.g: `getTax()` rather than `getTax`
6. Removed redundant invocations
7. More

Answer (score 0):

you are defining a variable, and assigning into it it's value times something.

```
var subTatal = subTatal * 0.06;
```

In this case, subTatal does not have a value.

I think you should read about variables and scopes.
Read the link below:
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp

Answer (score 0):

Your both function is returning the string :

```js
.... 

return  subTatal + ' with tax of ' + (subTatal)


... 

return  ' tax ' + getTax + 'plus subtotal ' + getSubTotal() + ' is ' + (myTotal);
```

You can go through this blog for converting strings to number:
https://coderwall.com/p/5tlhmw/converting-strings-to-number-in-javascript-pitfalls

Please make sure the what is the type of value you want to be returned form the function to use it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var subTatal = subTatal * 0.06;
```

is equivalent of

```
var subTatal = undefined;
subTatal = subTatal * 0.06;
```

> note, this subTatal is **not** the same as the one defined outside the function (learn scope)

Answer (score 0):

If you create a variable inside a function it will exists only inside that function, so if you call that variable from inside another it will be undefined.

There are two ways:

1. declare these variables as global at the top of your code just like `orderCount`
2. functions can have inputs and output, so you can pass to a function the variable you need and ask it to return the result, which can be saved into a variable and later used.

For example:

```
function getSubtotal(orderCount) {
  var subtotal = //do something 
  return subtotal } 

function getTax(subtotal) {
  var tax = //calculate tax
  return tax } 

var subtotal = getSubtotal(orderCount) 
var tax = getTax(subtotal)
```